Tower law for central simple algebras
In Field theory, if $$K\subset L$$ are both field extensions of $F$ then $[K:F]$ divides $[L:K]$. According to Wikipedia, if $\mathbb{K}$ is a simple sub-algebra of the central simple algebra $\mathbb{L}$ over $F$, then $\mathrm{dim}_F\mathbb{K}$ divides $\mathrm{dim}_F\mathbb{L}$. How can I show this? I thought of using the Artin-Wedderburn theorem which says $$\mathbb{L}\cong\mathrm{M}_n(\mathbb{D})$$ for some $n>0$ and with $\mathbb{D}$ a division ring but all I can extract from that is that $\mathrm{dim}_F\mathbb{K}$ and $\mathrm{dim}_F\mathbb{L}$ are both squares.

Let $\mathbb{L}$ be central simple over $F$ and let $\mathbb{K}$ be a simple sub-algebra (sharing a unit). Since $\mathbb{L}$ is central simple and $\mathbb{K}^\mathrm{op}$ is simple, it follows that $R = \mathbb{L}\otimes_F \mathbb{K}^\mathrm{op}$ is simple. Let $M$ denote the unique simple $R$-module. Since $\mathbb{L}$ has a natural $R$-module structure, it follows that there exists some integer $n$ such that $\mathbb{L} \cong M^n$ as $R$-modules.
Now, $R$ is simple, so $R\cong M_k(D)$ for some division ring $D$ by Artin-Wedderburn. From this, we can deduce that $M \cong D^k$. Taking dimensions, we get
$$\dim_F \mathbb{L} = n\dim_F M = nk \dim_F D,$$
as well as
$$\dim_F\mathbb{L}\cdot\dim_F\mathbb{K} = \dim_F R = k^2\dim_F D.$$
It follows that
$$\dim_F\mathbb{L} = n^2\dim_F D \cdot \dim_F\mathbb{K}.$$
This shows the required divisibility. If you want, you can actually sharpen this result slightly to get
$$\dim_F\mathbb{L} = \dim_F C_\mathbb{L}(\mathbb{K})\cdot \dim_F\mathbb{K},$$
where $C_\mathbb{L}(\mathbb{K})$ denotes the centralizer.

Is there a way to show this without referring to tensor products? I haven't worked with them before. I am familiar with modules.

@Ama It's hard to say if there isn't an alternative way of proving something, but I would venture to guess that this is among the more accessible proofs of this result. Why not take the chance to learn a bit about tensor products if you haven't encountered them before?
